# Reshaping and Stacking Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, formatting

I inherited a chunk of code and being a neophyte do not grasp its intricacies. It is formating 2x1 arrays generated to be passed as linesegments for matplotlib.LineCollect

```
                coar[t] = na[j] 
            coart = coar.reshape(-1,1,2)
            segments = np.hstack([coart[:-1],coart[1:]])
```

Please correct my terminology: 
It is taking iterations the 1x2 array na and placing them into 'coar' "an array of arrays"

```
   coar
    [[51 50]
     [52 50]
     [52 49]
     [52 48]] <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

How do the the arguments in reshape(-1,1,2) shape coar to be an"array within an array within an array"?

```
    coart:
    [[[51 50]]

     [[52 50]]

     [[52 49]]

     [[52 48]]] <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

And finally, hstack makes pairs of points to be plotted as line segments with LineCollect. It appears to take the -1 column with [:-1]? a negative column index? I do not understand how this all works

```
    [[[51 50]
      [52 50]]

     [[52 50]
      [52 49]]

     [[52 49]
      [52 48]]] <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

What is going on...
Any enlightenment on these function, formatting and data types would be fantastic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are a neophyte it would probably be helpful to point out that python has excellent documentation. First the np.reshape documentation can be found here: 
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html
but to give you the full story:
A -1 in the case of the reshape function tells numpy to infer that dimension by the length of that dimension.
So in this case if you check the shape of coart after the reshape you will find:

```
    coart.shape
    #output: (4,1,2)
```

For the next part you are confused about indexing and there is excellent documentation about indexing here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html
but to get to the gist of it, a -1 is interpreted by python as n + i where n is the length of the array and i is the negative number. So in your case -1 really means 3. Also since python uses 0 based indexing they do not count the last number so:

```
     coart[:-1]
     #output [[[51,50],[52,50],[52,49]]]
```

in your case means to take the array from element 0 to 2 (since the final number, which is 3 is not included)

```
    coart[1:]
```

means starting from element 1 and going to the end (so don't include element 0).

So as you can see the horizontal stacking tells it to stack row 0 on top of row 1 and row 1 on top of row 2 and row 2 on top of row 3.